# Initialising arc4random_uniform()

Tags: c++, arc4random

In c++ how do you use `arc4random_uniform` after initializing `srand()`? I'm not sure what I am doing but I initialized `srand()` as:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Then inside a for loop I have:

```
target = arc4random_uniform(workingArraySize);
```

However, I have an error saying `arc4random_uniform` is `undefined` and `identifier not found`. I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: The [online man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/arc4random_uniform) says there is no need for `srand()` as (a) it has its own separate `arc4random_stir()` for initialisation and (b) on first call it automatically calls `arc4random_stir()` if it hasn't already been done, so just use it without any initialisation at all. Now I've edited your question, I see you actually have a different problem...

Comment: sounds like you didn't include the header for arc4random_uniform?  According to the man page linked by Ken Y-N, you need  `#include <bsd/stdlib.h>`

Comment: For your other issue, [this seems to be the official source](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libc/crypt/arc4random.c) - it's not available by default on Windows